# How to make a jar file from a folder in windows?

Tags: jar, packaging

I downloaded a j-query theme rar file from Themeroller.
I had to replace one png inside that folder so I can get different color of icons. So I used winrar to extract the jar-file as a folder and replaced that one file in that folder.

Now, how can I package that folder and all its subfolders into a .jar file again? I can only find instructions to package java classes to jar-files but I just want to package this folder c:\mytheme2\ and its subfolders back to a .jar package.

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to command prompt.
2. Navigate in it to the directory/folder which you would like to include in the jar file including all its subfolders
3. Write, depending on your jdk-path and the name you want fro your jar file, the following command in command prompt:

> ```
> "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\jar.exe" -cvf JarFileName.jar FolderName
> ```